# How to grab the value of a variable that is tabbed using bash

Tags: bash, go, scripting

I have a golang file named ver.go consisting of 1 variable.

```
const (
    ver = "1.1.1"
)
```

I want to be able to output 1.1.1 using a bash command. I am able to do this without a problem if we get rid of the tab at the beginning and the spaces like so

```
const (
ver="1.1.1"
)
```

by using this command `awk -F= '/^ver=/{print $2}' ver.go | sed -e 's/^"//' -e 's/"$//'`

However, since it must be formatted properly with `gofmt` I can't seem to figure it out with the tab in there as well as the space after the equal sign

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you want to allow spaces, tell the regex to allow spaces. `[[:space:]]*` is not hard to sprinkle in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution if you just want `"1.1.1"` from the file `ver.go` is to let `sed` do the work for you. You can use the normal substitution form with a single backreference to capture the `"1.1.1"` and reinsert it as the replacement for the entire line. You can use `sed -n` to suppress output of normal pattern-space and add a `p` after the substitution so that only the line matching your REGEX prints following successful substitution, e..g

```
sed -n 's/^[[:space:]]*ver[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*"\([^"][^"]*\).*$/\1/p' ver.go
```

This will work with or without the spaces (or tabs) before the `"ver"`.

**Example Use/Output**

With your `ver.go` contents, you would get:

```
$ sed -n 's/^[[:space:]]*ver[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*"\([^"][^"]*\).*$/\1/p' ver.go
1.1.1
```

If I misunderstood what you are after, please let me know. If you have further questions, just drop a comment below.

Comment: Glad to help. Just goes to show there is always more than one way to *skin-the-cat* with shell commands `:)`

Answer (score 2):

You may use this awk:

```
awk -F= '$1 ~ /^[[:blank:]]*ver/{gsub(/["[:blank:]]+/, ""); print $2}' file
```

```
1.1.1
```

Answer (score 1):

With `bash` and Parameter Expansion to remove all `"`:

```
while read -r key x value; do [[ "$key" == "ver" ]] && echo "${value//\"/}"; done < ver.go
```

Output:

```
1.1.1
```